# How to add placeholder image for gif image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, animated-gif

I have a line code as below and may I know how to add in placeholder image into it?

```
#import "UIImage+animatedGIF.h"

_imgPromotion_Image.image = [UIImage animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_strPromotion_Image]];
```

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: You can put your placeholder to your `_imgPromotion_Image ` first. asynchronous download the gif in background. When the download finished, display it

Comment: @QuocNguyen mind to show me some sample code? thanks!

Comment: sorry about it, just suggest. You should try it yourself first

Comment: I have tried something like this but it does not work.    `[_imgProductImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strProductImage] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Placeholder.png"]];`. Gif will not animate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add following pods

**pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 4.4.1'**

**pod 'SDWebImage/GIF'**

now import

```
#import "FLAnimatedImage.h"
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>
```

to your ViewController, then try--

```
NSString *urlStr = @"https://staticimg.ngmm365.com/0dd3a526e657396c3dfba57799a2e5e4-w750_h336.gif";

FLAnimatedImageView *gifImageView  = [[FLAnimatedImageView alloc] init];
gifImageView.contentMode =  UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
CGFloat y = (self.view.frame.size.height-self.view.frame.size.width)/2;
gifImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, y, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.width);
[self.view addSubview:gifImageView];

[gifImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

[output result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MK4Gx.gif)